# filtering the array of objects based on other array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Hi all i have two array of objects like as below

```
const selectedCodes = [
  { id: 1, modifiedObject: null, originalObject: {id: 23, name: 'test'}},
  { id: 2, modifiedObject: {id: 24, name: 'test2'}, originalObject: null },
  ....
  ....
];
```

another array of objects like as below

```
const originalCodes = [
  { id: 23, name: 'test' },
  { id: 24, name: 'test2'},
  { id: 25, name: 'test3' },
  { id: 26, name: 'test4' }
];
```

I am looking for the results that originalCodes should return these two items

```
const originalCodes = [
      { id: 25, name: 'test3' },
      { id: 26, name: 'test4' }
    ];
```

here i would like to filter the results of originalCodes array based on id available from selectedCodes array modifiedObject/ originalObject Id's and it is always only one object per index either modified object and original object will be present.

Could any one please let me know or any ideas on how can i achieve the results, Many thanks in advance.

i have tried below

```
const removedArrays = selectCodes.reduce((acc, item) => {
   console.log(item)// here i need to verify  with other array of objects
},[{}])
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: I am trying to do with reduce like this `const removedArrays = selectedCodes.reduce((acc) => {
   console.log(acc)
},[{}])` but could not be able to know how to loop through other array

Comment: @NinaScholz i updated my question

Comment: does the (nested) objects have the same object reference?

Comment: the nested objects looks like same as original objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is to filter out the `originalCodes` items that are present as `name` property in either `originalObject` or `modifiedObject`, solution could be as simple as that:

```js
const selectedCodes = [{id:1,modifiedObject:null,originalObject:{id:23,name:"test"}},{id:2,modifiedObject:{id:24,name:"test2"},originalObject:null}],
      originalCodes = [{id:23,name:"test"},{id:24,name:"test2"},{id:25,name:"test3"},{id:26,name:"test4"}],
      
      
      result = originalCodes.filter(({id}) => 
                  !selectedCodes.some(({originalObject, modifiedObject}) => {
                    const {id: id1} = (originalObject||{}),
                          {id: id2} = (modifiedObject||{})
                    return id == id1 || id == id2
                  })
               )
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: thanks and is it possible to return the originalCodes with out creating new variable

Comment: you have mentioned `react.js` among your tags, so I presumed you would prefer immutable approach (which is usually the case to manipulate the state). however, if having extra variable is an issue for some reason (and reassign source variable to resulting array is not an option either), you may come up with some combination of `for(..`-loop coupled with `.splice()`, dropping the items that evaluated truthy by above `.some()`-method.

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear what you are looking for. It sounds like you want find `originalCodes` which do not exist in the `selectedCodes`. If so then the following may work for you:

```js
const selectedCodes = [
  { id: 1, modifiedObject: null, originalObject: {id: 23, name: 'test'}},
  { id: 2, modifiedObject: {id: 24, name: 'test2'}, originalObject: null }
];

const originalCodes = [
  { id: 23, name: 'test' },
  { id: 24, name: 'test2'},
  { id: 25, name: 'test3' },
  { id: 26, name: 'test4' }
];

const filteredCodes = originalCodes.filter(function(item) {
  return !(selectedCodes.find(element => (element.originalObject && element.originalObject.id) == item.id) || selectedCodes.find(element => (element.modifiedObject && element.modifiedObject.id) == item.id));
});

console.log(filteredCodes);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i would need the result completely reverse (i.e) would like to get the objects contains 25 and 26

Comment: Updated. Just switched the logic by appending `!` (not)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const selectedCodes=[{id:1,modifiedObject:null,originalObject:{id:23,name:"test"}},{id:2,modifiedObject:{id:24,name:"test2"},originalObject:null}],originalCodes=[{id:23,name:"test"},{id:24,name:"test2"},{id:25,name:"test3"},{id:26,name:"test4"}];

let result = originalCodes.filter(({id}) => 
    !selectedCodes.find(e => 
    (e.originalObject?e.originalObject.id:e.modifiedObject.id) === id ))


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stringify the objects for an `exclude` object and filter `originalCodes`.

This approach requires all objects to have the same order of all properties.

```js
const
    selectedCodes = [{ id: 1, modifiedObject: null, originalObject: { id: 23, name: 'test' } }, { id: 2, modifiedObject: { id: 24, name: 'test2' }, originalObject: null }],
    originalCodes = [{ id: 23, name: 'test' }, { id: 24, name: 'test2'}, { id: 25, name: 'test3' }, { id: 26, name: 'test4' }],
    exclude = Object.fromEntries(selectedCodes.map(o => [JSON.stringify(o.originalObject || o.modifiedObject), true])),
    result = originalCodes.filter(o => !exclude[JSON.stringify(o)]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```